# Windows 7 how to purge entries in Run command window

Tags: windows-7, run-dialog

I would like to know, how to delete the entries in the `Run` Command prompt/window in Windows 7, for a normal user i.e. that does not have administrative privileges.

[image: run]

Comment: I would just use CCLeaner to acomplish this.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

1. Open Taskbar and Start Menu Properties by clicking the `Start > Control Panel > Appearance and Personalization > Taskbar and Start Menu`.
2. Click the Start Menu tab, and then, under Privacy, clear the Store and display a list of recently opened programs check box.

Source: [Clear the Run history on the Start menu](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows-vista/Clear-the-Run-history-on-the-Start-menu) at Microsoft.com.

Comment: Perfect answer. Also no reboot/ re-logging required :).

Answer (score 2):

**The entries are stored in Regedit**

Open up regedit.exe through the start menu run box, and then navigate down to the following key:

`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\RunMRU`

You’ll see all your recent commands on the right, and you can delete any of the keys that contain your commands. You’ll have to logoff and then back on, but the list should be clean.

**But since a standard user cannot modify the registry, the best option would be not to save the information in the first place, as explained in the previous answer by** @CharlieRB.

Comment: I've removed and logged off but the deleted entries still show up in the Run window.